# Copy-Item : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: appdata, copy-item

I am trying to copy configuration files for an Active X controller to all user profiles on remote computers and I am running into problems. I have tried several variations of the code to no avail, my most recent, simplified code is shown below which is generating  a path format not supported error:

```
$From = "C:\Interactive" $To = "C:\Users\$user\appdata\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Downloaded Program Files" ForEach ($user in (Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Exclude Public)){Copy-Item -Path $From -Destination $To}
```

I assume there is an argument I am missing or some sort of syntax but I cannot find it. I plan on deploying this script using PS App Deploy Toolkit through SCCM when it is working (Group Policy is not currently a viable solution for me at this time)

I have spent my day trying to find a working script and I have come up empty. I used to use Set-ActiveSetup Stub ExePath but that seems to not be working any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a way that works for me.  I am including how I went about it, ignore the part with the DLL registration-

```
        $Source = "C:\Temp\Downloaded Program Files"
    $Destination = "C:\users\*"
    $Items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination

    foreach ($Item in $Items)
        {
             Write-Verbose "List of folders: $item" -Verbose    ##added for visibility when I was testing
             Copy-Item $Source -Destination "$item\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" -Force -Recurse
             $CKIDLL = "`"$item\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Downloaded Program Files\CKInteractiveDriver.dll`""
             Start-Process -Filepath 'regsvr32.exe' -Args "/s $CKIDLL"
        }
```